# New environment using mdframed

Tags: environments, mdframed

I'm trying to write a collection of problems and their solutions for my course's textbook. I've created an exercise environment. I'm currently using the `mdframed` package to create a leftbar that spans the exercise descriptions.

Here are some of my issues and questions:

- Is it possible to create an exercise environment like mine so that "Exercise ---" appears on the same line as the exercise description (so no line breaks)?
- Should the leftbar in my example be changed any? Does it go too far above/below the text? It seems like the bar goes farther above the text than it does below the text.
- How would I change my example so that instead of a leftbar, the entire exercise environment (not including the solutions) is shaded a light gray?

  ```
  \documentclass[11pt]{article}

  \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
  \usepackage{color, linegoal}
  \usepackage{amsthm,array}
  \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
  \usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}

  % Exercise environment
  \definecolor{ExerciseColor}{gray}{0.65}

  \newenvironment{exercise}[1]
  {\mdfsetup{
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=4pt,
  leftmargin=-13pt,
  splitbottomskip=0ex,
  splittopskip=0ex,
  topline=false,
  leftline=true,
  bottomline=false,
  rightline=false,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
  innerlinewidth=2pt,
  font=\normalfont,
  frametitle={\textbf{Exercise #1.}}, 
  linecolor=ExerciseColor,
  }
  \begin{mdframed}%
  }
  {\end{mdframed}}

  % Solution environment
  \newenvironment{solution}{\begin{proof}[\itshape Solution]}{\end{proof}}

  \begin{document}
  \title{Title}
  \author{Author}
  \date{\today}
  \maketitle

  \section*{\centering \bfseries \S 1.3 Exercises}

  \begin{exercise}{1.3.1}
  Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an equation:
  \[
  a + b = c.
  \]
  Here is an exercise. 
  \end{exercise}
  \begin{solution}
  Here is my solution. Here is an equation:
  \[
  1+2 = 3.
  \]
  Here is my solution. 
  \end{solution}

  \begin{exercise}{1.3.5}
  Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an equation:
  \[
  a + b = c.
  \]
  Here is an exercise. 
  \end{exercise}
  \begin{solution}
  Here is my solution.
  \end{solution}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image: Output:]

Comment: Why are you numbering the exercises manually?

Comment: I want a collection of solved problems to distribute to students. I only intend on solving a select few of the exercises in the textbook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another similar approach, but this time using the interface provided by the [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package; the idea is to define the structure as a theorem-like one, and use the `mdframed` key provided by `thmtools`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\definecolor{ExerciseColor}{gray}{0.65}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=0.5em,
mdframed={
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep,
  hidealllines=true,
  backgroundcolor={ExerciseColor!20},
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt}
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle,name=Exercise]{exer}
\newenvironment{exercise}[1]
  {\renewcommand\theexer{#1}\begin{exer}}
  {\end{exer}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}{1.3.5}
Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an equation:
\[
a + b = c.
\]
Here is an exercise. 
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}{1.3.7}
Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an exercise. Here is an equation:
\[
a + b = c.
\]
Here is an exercise. 
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you notice my message in the chat. I uploaded the new version with a lot of new hooks ;-)

Answer (score 5):

A lot of questions.

> - Is it possible to create an exercise environment like mine so that "Exercise ---" appears on the same line as the exercise description (so no line breaks)?

In this case I suggest to define a normal theorem environment with `newtheorem` and surround the environment with `mdframed`:
\definecolor{ExerciseColor}{gray}{0.65}

```
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
\mdfdefinestyle{exercise}{%
skipabove=\topsep,skipbelow=\topsep,
innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=4pt,
leftmargin=-13pt,splitbottomskip=0ex,
splittopskip=0ex,topline=false,leftline=true,
bottomline=false,rightline=false,
innerrightmargin=0pt,innerlinewidth=2pt,
font=\normalfont,linecolor=ExerciseColor,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=exercise]{exercise}
```

Of course the numbering scheme of `exercise` must be modified to your needs. I don't know why you are using a manual count.

> - Should the leftbar in my example be changed any? Does it go too far above/below the text? It seems like the bar goes farther above the text than it does below the text.

This can be fixed if you use `ntheorem` and `mdframed` with the option `ntheorem=true` to declare your theorems.

```
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
\mdfdefinestyle{exercise}{%
skipabove=\topsep,skipbelow=\topsep,
innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=4pt,
leftmargin=-13pt,splitbottomskip=0ex,
splittopskip=0ex,topline=false,leftline=true,
bottomline=false,rightline=false,
innerrightmargin=0pt,innerlinewidth=2pt,
font=\normalfont,linecolor=ExerciseColor,ntheorem=true,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=exercise]{exercise}
```

> - How would I change my example so that instead of a leftbar, the entire exercise environment (not including the solutions) is shaded a light gray?

Also with `\surroundwithmdframed`.